# How to implement a Scala 3 macro that adds the inline keyword (aka Flag) to a Def/Val

Tags: scala, macros, inline, scala-macros, scala-3

I am currently implementing a macro annotation called [getInline](https://github.com/mdedetrich/get-inline) and I am hitting an issue where specifically for Scala 3 macro annotations I can't seem to write such a macro.

Given we have the following macro annotation

```
@experimental class getInline extends MacroAnnotation {
  override def transform(using quotes: Quotes)(
      tree: quotes.reflect.Definition
  ): List[quotes.reflect.Definition]
```

and with the following body where we implement the macro

```
    tree match {
      case e@ DefDef(name, params, tpt, rhs) =>
        val flagsWithInline = e.symbol.flags | Flags.Inline

        val methodWithInline = Symbol.newMethod(tree.symbol.owner,
                         e.name,
                         e.symbol.typeRef,
                         flagsWithInline,
                         e.symbol.privateWithin.map(_.termSymbol).getOrElse(Symbol.noSymbol)
        )

        ???
      case e: ValDef =>
        val flagsWithInline = e.symbol.flags | Flags.Inline

        val valWithInline = Symbol.newVal(tree.symbol.owner,
                      e.name,
                      e.symbol.typeRef,
                      flagsWithInline,
                      e.symbol.privateWithin.map(_.termSymbol).getOrElse(Symbol.noSymbol)
        )

        ???
    }
  }
```

The core problem I have is how to return a new AST tree (in place of `???`) with the `methodWithInline` and `valWithInline` respectively. Assuming we have the following code that calls the macro annotation

```
@getInline final def myVal = 5
```

The tree returned by `methodWithInline` using the `.show` method is

```
inline final def myVal: org.mdedetrich.Test.myVal = 5
```

Which is exactly what we want. The problem is that if we return `methodWithInline` as is using `List(DefDef(methodWithInline, _ => e.rhs))` as the implementation of the macro annotation then the following error message appears

```
[error]   |Transformed tree for @getInline final def myVal: Int = 5 was not return by `(new org.mdedetrich.getinline.getInline()).transform(..)` during macro expansion
```

It appears that the proper way to do this is to use `DefDef.copy` on the current tree (which in our case is represented by the value `e`). The problem here is that `DefDef.copy` does not appear to accept an altered list of `Flags` (represented by the `flagsWithInline` variable).